# Why is 032 different than 32 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, octal

I have noticed Ruby behaves differently when working with 032 and 32. I once got syntax errors for having 032 instead of just 32 in my code. Can someone explain this to me? Or is there something really wrong with my code itself?

Comment: We can explain why `032` is different than `32`, but we can't explain why it was an error in your code unless you provide a sample with the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're seeing is `032` is an octal representation, and `32` is decimal:

```
>> 032 #=> 26
>> 32 #=> 32
>> "32".to_i(8) #=> 26
>> "32".to_i(10) #=> 32
```

And, just for completeness, you might need to deal with hexadecimal:

```
>> 0x32 #=> 50
>> "32".to_i(16) #=> 50
```

and binary:

```
>> 0b100000 #=> 32
>> 32.to_s(2) #=> "100000"
```

Answer (score 5):

When you have a zero in front of your number, Ruby interprets it as an [octal(base 8 number)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

You syntax error is probably something like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :020 > 08
SyntaxError: (irb):20: Invalid octal digit
```

Comment: That is, in a notation starting with `0`, whenever you have `8` or `9`, which should not appear in an octal representation, you get an error.

Answer (score 4):

If you start a number with 0 (zero), ruby treats it as an octal, so you normally don't want the zero. You'll have to be more specific about the syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

i don't know about syntax errors, but when you prefix a number with zero it means it's octal (base-8)... so 032 is actually 26 in decimal